# ROS industrial for IRB-360

Tags: ros, ros-industrial, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

newbie here, scoping a project where I am hoping to control a IRB-360 with a control and vision system on ROS. I am also working with an IRC5 controller.

I am just wondering if the current ABB ROS package supports the control of the IRB-360 or robots where a specific moveit package?

Thanks,
Brian.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277312/ros-industrial-for-irb-360/) by [BrianH](https://answers.ros.org/users/32860/brianh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty certain the driver (`abb_driver`) will not have any difficulty with the IRB 360 (everything is done in joint space), but there is currently no (built-in) support for parallel kinematics in ROS (at least not in the default KDL interfaces, custom IK solvers can do anything). This means no support in urdf/xacro, nor in MoveIt.

The current accepted work-around is to model the kinematics as a "stick on a ball joint" and have a specialised node do the IK/FK for you. This was done for the [Blue WorkForce Ragnar Robot](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2015/12/12/ragnar) (code: [blueworkforce/ROSRagnarEDU](https://github.com/blueworkforce/ROSRagnarEDU)) and the [Yaskawa Motoman MPP3H](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman_experimental/pull/20).

This setup could work for the IRB 360, but I haven't seen it done yet, so I can't be certain.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-05**:
Note: when I write: no support for parallel kinematics, I mean that it's impossible to have a joint with `> 1` parent. So initialisation of FK/IK components from the urdf is difficult. There are some tricks that can be used to at least get visualisation going though.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2018-08-04**:
Sir, could I command joint velocity with ABB robot in ROS? For example, we can use URScript to control the joint velocity of Universal Robot for real-time control. However, I can barely find info on the real-time joint velocity tracking performance on the other robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-04**:
Please ask this as a separate question. Apart from the fact that you want to use an ABB, I don't see any connecting to the Q&A that you posted your comment on.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2018-08-04**:
Thank you for your quick response as always. I have posted my question in the following link and I wonder if you may give me some suggestions? Thank you.

#q299622.